# Spring Boot + MongoDB: update and get size in one query

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot 2.1.3.RELEASE and MongoDB. I need to update a list in a document and get the count of that list in one query.

Document example:

```
  @Data
  public class Company {
    @Id
    private String id;

    private List<String> departments; 
  }
```

Update query:

```
mongoTemplate.updateFirst(query(where("_id").is("companyId")),
        new Update().pull("departments", "IT"),
        "companyCollection");
```

Count query:

```
final Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
        match(where("_id").is("companyId")),
        project()
            .and("departments")
            .size()
            .as("count")
    );
```

It has to be atomic. Is there a way to achieve this?